# How to limit Google Places Autocomplete to not include Address?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

How to limit Google Places Autocomplete to not include Address? I currently have my setup

```
class FilterVC: UIViewController, GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

// MARK: SEARCH BAR

@IBAction func searchBarAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autocompleteController.delegate = self
    placeAutocomplete(resultsViewController: autocompleteController)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.hiGreyishBrownTwo
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.hiGreyishBrownTwo]
    present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func placeAutocomplete(resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    var placeClient = GMSPlacesClient()
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .city
    filter.country = "USA"
    resultsViewController.autocompleteFilter = filter

    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        DataService.instance.place = place
        FillAddress(place: place)
        fillAddressForm()

        print(DataService.instance._address_line1)
         print(DataService.instance._city)
         print(DataService.instance._postalCode)
         print(DataService.instance._state)
         print(DataService.instance._country)
        DataService.instance.addressLabel = place.formattedAddress
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
    print("ERROR \(error) Autocomplete")
}
```

I tried using a GMSAutocompleteFilter to limit my results to only include state city, zip, country. I don't want to display address in the autocomplete controller. When I do this, it only displays Country and city, I can't enter zip code. How would I make that available? I'm not quite sure what I'm missing or what the next step to take is. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was going to take this off since I found a solution, but just in case some one runs into a similar issue, a very easy fix is to set filter type to region.

```
func placeAutocomplete(resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    var placeClient = GMSPlacesClient()
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.country = "USA"
    filter.type = .region

    resultsViewController.autocompleteFilter = filter
```

This will limit the search to not include address. When trying .city, that eliminated to much. Well hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: No need to remove your question; simply mark it as the correct answer so others can benefit from this.